# How can i find sessions on my website using Google-Analytics API?

Tags: session, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am a student and want to knows how can i find sessions, users etc on any website using google analytics API.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Check the documentation make an attempt if you have any issues edit your question include your code and describe your issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Google Analytics Core Reporting API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference (or v4 Reporting API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/)

You need to install a client library based on your language used (es: PHP).

Or, more simple, you can use Google Apps Script: https://www.appsscript.it/tutorial/generare-report-automatici-con-i-dati-di-google-analytics-in-google-sheets/